# FMJ not working on initial download

Tags: windows-7, fmj

I've written some application code using JMF, but would like to switch to FMJ to make delivery easier.

Unfortunately, on my Windows 7 laptop (where JMF works fine once installed), I downloaded fmj-20070928-0938.zip, uncompressed it, and ran fmjstudio.bat.  As soon as I click on the webcam icon, I get errors which start with "WARNING: com.lti.civil.CaptureException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Temp\fmj-extracted\native\win32-x86\civil.dll: Can't find dependent libraries"

Any suggestions?

Comment: A moderator is welcome to close this question, as there is another one which talks about 32-bit/64-bit and FMJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is probably not a complete answer, a partial answer is that FMJ uses 32-bit libraries.  I am fairly sure I was using a 64-bit java.

On a different Windows 7 computer I successfully got fmjstudio to run using a 32-bit java.  Next step is getting it to recognize the camera for my own app rather than fmjstudio.

Comment: help me getting installed please

Comment: +anshulkatta try this: download fmj-20070928-0938.zip, uncompress it, and run fmjstudio.bat.  Then, if necessary, formulate a more detailed question.

Comment: i have done with JAVACV , now its working...moreover with fmj the webcam is slow in output